# How to make a bot to automatically open Zoom meeting and enter class when it's time in the schedule by using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I am making a bot to automatically open Zoom meeting and enter the class when it's time. I set the time when it is from 8:00 PM to 8:10 PM  the computer will automatically open Zoom and enter the code and password, but it's not running. I have tried many ways but nothing happen. So hopefully someone can help to fix this.
***Thank you very much!***

Here is my code

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pyttsx3
import os



#---------------------------------------------------------


# Robot speech
# Jarvis_brain = speak
# Jarvis_mouth = engine
assistant= "Jarvis" # Iron man Fan
Jarvis_mouth = pyttsx3.init()
Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("rate", 140)
voices = Jarvis_mouth.getProperty("voices")
Jarvis_mouth.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)

def Jarvis_brain(audio):
    print("Jarvis: " + audio)
    Jarvis_mouth.say(audio)
    Jarvis_mouth.runAndWait()
  

def sign_in(meetingid, pswd):
    #Opens up the zoom app
    #change the path specific to your computer
    
    #If on windows use below line for opening zoom
    #subprocess.call('C:\\myprogram.exe')
    
    #If on mac / Linux use below line for opening zoom
    subprocess.call(["C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe"])

    time.sleep(1)
    
    #clicks the join button
    join_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('join_button.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(join_btn)
    pyautogui.click()

    # Type the meeting ID
    meeting_id_btn =  pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('meeting_id_button.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(meeting_id_btn)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.write(meetingid)

    # Hits the join button
    join_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('join_btn.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(join_btn)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    #Types the password and hits enter
    meeting_pswd_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('meeting_pswd1.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(meeting_pswd_btn)
    pyautogui.click()
    pyautogui.write(pswd)
    pyautogui.press('enter')

# Reading the file
df = pd.read_csv('timings.csv')

while True:
    # checking of the current time exists in our csv file
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%A %H:%M")

    if now in str(df['timings1']) and now in str(df['timings2']):

        row1 = df.loc[df['timings1'] >= now] # if the time is 8 PM or more it will open Zoom and enter the code
        row2 = df.loc[df['timings2'] <= now] ## if the time is 8:10 PM or less it will open Zoom and enter the code

        m_id = str(row1,row2.iloc[0,1])
        m_pswd = str(row1,row2.iloc[0,2])

        sign_in(m_id, m_pswd)
        Jarvis_brain('signed in')
        time.sleep(60)
    else:
        Jarvis_brain("error. please try again")
```

Here is the file to set the schedule: timings.csv

timings1 and timing2: day and time

```
timings1, timings2, meetingid, meetpswd
Monday 20:06, Monday 20:40, 456 884 2391, 12345670
```

***Thanks for helping me.***

Comment: [github zoom bot](https://github.com/sujaysathya/bunk_bot) this might help you

Comment: The second comment in `sign_in` has a case apparently for running on LInux, but the path involved is not likely to succeed.  Is this running on `wine` on Linux?

Comment: I guess Zoom already has an inbuilt feature for this thing. But, I like your way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do have a working zoom link e.g.

```
https://yourCompanyName.zoom.us/j/1234567890
```

To launch zoom on MacOS (*tested*) and Linux (*untested*) you can do a C `system(...)`  call like this:

```
system("open -a zoom.us 'https://yourCompanyName.zoom.us/j/1234567890'");
```

Which in Python would translate to:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["open", "-a", "zoom.us", "https://yourCompanyName.zoom.us/j/1234567890"])
```

But judging from your code you are clearly on Windows environment.
Based on https://superuser.com/a/1563359 this *should* work:

```
%APPDATA%\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe "url=https://yourCompanyName.zoom.us/j/1234567890"
```

i.e. in Python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["%APPDATA%\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe", "\"url=https://yourCompanyName.zoom.us/j/1234567890\""])
```

You should now have the ability to programmatically launch your Zoom room.
I leave the time trigger as an exercise.

Also take into account the process of launching Zoom and connecting also takes some time so it would be advisable to give it a head start to be on schedule.

There is no error handling here if anything goes wrong. But that's beyond this question.